# Combine my ApplicationsDbContext with IdentityDbContext no key defined using MVC 5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I was combining my existing DBContext with the new IdentityDbContext in MVC 5.  I managed to combine the two contexts but when I ran my application and the model was being created I was presented with the following error message:

Context.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Context.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked out how to fix it after doing a bit of reading.

Create the two following configuration classes (keeps it clean in your OnModelCreating method as your database grows and relationships between tables increase)

```
public class IdentityUserLoginConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin>
{

    public IdentityUserLoginConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(iul => iul.UserId);
    }

}

public class IdentityUserRoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserRole>
{

    public IdentityUserRoleConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(iur => iur.RoleId);
    }

}
```

In the OnModelCreating method within your Applications DbContext add the two configurations outlined above to the model:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserLoginConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserRoleConfiguration());

    }
```

This should now get rid of the error methods when your model is being created.  It did for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with the configuration classes.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
    }
```

Comment: It's far tidier if you create separate configuration classes.  If you add it all into the OnModelCreating method as you've shown above and as the database grows it will fill up extremely quickly...