# Change Value in MS SQL / Visual Studio 2013 using MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to edit a simple bit value in my MS SQL / MVC 5 application, and I am completely stuck. What I'm trying to do is set a bit value to true if a user logs on. The problem is, I have no idea how to properly access the data, change the information, and post it back to the SQL server.

The code I am trying to access lives in a modified ASP.net identity database. Therefore, property and table entry was performed using Migration, and all other associated procedures as outlined here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594. I have made a simple Friends Model in an effort to meet the needs of the application.

Here is the code to the model:

```
public class Friendsdb : DbContext
{
    public Friendsdb() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       ..// irrelevant code
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> UserDetails { get; set; } //has the IsLoggedin bit value

    }
}
```

In short, I used basic routing in order to get to the appropriate action. Which is:

```
    public ActionResult Ifloggedin()
    {
        if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I've omitted some code as it is not functional. I have tried several things, to edit the bit value but all has failed. If someone can lead me in the right direction regarding this, I would be grateful.

**Update:**

While implementing the suggested solution I recieved the following validation error: EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. After some research, I was able to implement the answer found on this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912704/combine-my-applicationsdbcontext-with-identitydbcontext-no-key-defined-using-mvc).

With this error out of the way, "Sequence contains no elements" is giving me trouble. This was solved by using "FirstOrDefault" instead of "First" in peinearydevelopment's answer, however, when employeed I get the following fault: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I tried about a dozen different suggestions to solve the issue but none have worked. A very weak guess is that DB.UserDetails is a null value, and currently, I am not sure how to correct the issue.

**Update Two:**

It seems that there was a context built by Microsoft that should be used when updating identity Fields, called: IdentityDbContext. Once I researched, and figured out the correct syntax, I was able to update the value. The correct code is below:

```
    public ActionResult IsUserLoggedIn ()
    {
        var UserId = HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
        if (ModelState.IsValid && HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> db = new IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>();

            db.Users.First(u => u.Id == UserId).IsUserOnline = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Thank you to peinearydevelopment for leading me in the right direction. As a final note, I will add error checking later.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine if a user is logged in...that's what your doing inside of your Ifloggedin() method User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns a bool that lets you know if the current user is logged in. What are you trying to write back to the database?

Comment: You have the method decorated with an Authorize attribute too so they will ALWAYS be logged in and that check is redundant.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply, the ultimate goal is to check the status of a user in real time. I am trying to create "friends list" functionality, by querying the database for users; I thought the easiest way to tell if someone was on-line would be to check this resource. There is a Boolean value in the AspNetUsers table named IsUserOnline. If the friend is online, this will equal true, else false. I realize now that I am trying to write the return of IsAuthenticated to the aforementioned value.  I have been coding for less than a month, so MVC and C# are new to me.

Comment: Thank you br4d, I will remove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want something like this:

```
using (var context = new Friendsdb())
{
  context.UserDetails.First(userDetail => userDetail.Id == HttpContext.User.Id).IsLoggedin = true;
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You will have to take this as pseudocode as I'm unsure what you have on your models, but the above Entity Framework code is what you should need to set that bit value in the database.

Comment: Thank you for this, I think I am on the right track, when implementing your solution into my code, I get the following error: Sequence contains no elements. As I've said in my update, I am not sure what the right course of action is.

Comment: That would seem to indicate that your clause inside First isn't returning anything, so possibly you are looking at the wrong data. I don't know if you actually have Id fields for all of these, possibly only username? You will have to debug through and see what you have available to lookup based off of.